# Adding icon to QDialog

Tags: c++, qt

How can I add an icon to QDialog, but not the icon on a frame, I need to place an icon inside this dialog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use QLabel and set the pixmap properties to display the image. It's not an icon though